# What's the correct format for this case?

Tags: javascript, format

```
  <select name="test" id="<? echo $idtabel.'-'.$p.'-'. 1 .'; ?>" 
   onChange="javascript:document.getElementById
   ('<? echo $idtabel.'-'.$p.'-'. 1 .'b';?>')
   .value=document.getElementById('<? echo $idtabel.'-'.$p.'-'. 1 .'; ?>')
   .value;">
```

What's the correct format for this case? I need input a php code into javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .

```
<select name="test" id="<?php echo $idtabel.'-'.$p.'-'. 1; ?>" onChange="javascript:document.getElementById('<?php echo $idtabel.'-'.$p.'-'. 1 .'b'; ?>').value=document.getElementById('<?php echo $idtabel.'-'.$p.'-'. 1; ?>').value;">
```

Comment: A php tag works like this.  <?php /* enter you code here */ ?>